Expo React Native: cannot connect API localhost using http from Android device
So, I'm working with Expo and React Native. I'm having problems trying to connect to my local API via http from an Android device.
If I tried from the emulator using http://10.0.2.2:PORT_NUMBER, it works, but I cannot develop the app from the emulator because I need several features that only a device can offer (camera, bluetooth, etc).
I tried the next that I found but they're not working, except one using ngrok:

Change URL localhost to 10.0.2.2 (only works in the emulator)
Change the URL to my local IP 192.168.x.x. It does not work from my device, I can get access from the browser though.
I already had the right configuration in the app.json:

...
[
  "expo-build-properties",
  {
    "android": {
      "usesCleartextTraffic": true
    }
  }
],
...


ngrok: it was the only way to make it work, but because it uses https
I tried several public APIs but all of them are using https, so they're working

My teammate does not have any problem running the same code but using an Ios device.
I think the solution should not be changing the local API to https or use ngrok, is it just impossible to connect via http from an Android device?
Thank you in advance!

Did you tried port forwarding the expo port(19000) in your system.

I was able to fix this by removing the library detox and @config-plugins/detox. I don't know what was going on exactly, but it fixed it.
Another solution is to add this in the app.json (but it didn't work for me):
      [
        '@config-plugins/detox',
        {
          subdomains: '*',
        },
      ],

Source: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19585
